# laravel eloquent using a json object to search and array in my database

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, eloquent

I have a json object

```
'developer' => 
  array (
    'count' => 1,
    'docPosition' => 100,
    'countCv' => 1,
    'weight' => '0.077',
  ),
  'Software Engineer' => 
  array (
    'count' => 4,
    'docPosition' => 716,
    'countCv' => 4,
    'weight' => '0.308',
  ),
  'engineer' => 
  array (
    'count' => 5,
    'docPosition' => 725,
    'countCv' => 5,
    'weight' => '0.385',
  ),
  'Software Development Engineer' => 
  array (
    'count' => 1,
    'docPosition' => 1272,
    'countCv' => 1,
    'weight' => '0.077',
  ),
  'Development Engineer' => 
  array (
    'count' => 1,
    'docPosition' => 1281,
    'countCv' => 1,
    'weight' => '0.077',
  ),
  'Contract' => 
  array (
    'count' => 1,
    'docPosition' => 1303,
    'countCv' => 1,
    'weight' => '0.077',
  ),
)
```

I want to get the keys of the object (developer, Software Engineer, engineer, etc) and use them to search the db for matches that are in a field called Industry that is an array.  I am unsure about the following.

1. How to get the keys on the object and turn it into an array.
2. Search my db for any matches between the array I created and the array in the field Industry.

I have searched google and stack and have not found anything helpful.
Any ideas or strategies would be appreciated.

Comment: What SQL you are using? array is a vendor-specific column type. iirc eloquent just converts arrays to strings to persist it in the db.

Comment: @AlexBlex I am using mySql

Comment: mysql does not have array types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make that json object into a Collection :

```
$collection=collect(json_decode($yourObject);
```

And get the keys :

```
$keys = $collection->keys();
```

And you can retrieve from your data like this

```
$data = collect($yourData);
$results = $keys->each(function($key){
             $data->only($key);
             //do your logic with it
});
```

[you can learn more about it here : Laravel Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-only)